# Delphi-like GUI designer for Python

Tags: python, user-interface, form-designer

Is there any GUI toolkit for Python with form designer similar to Delphi, eg where one can drag and drop controls to form, move them around etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) (now from Nokia), which uses [Qt Designer](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/appdev/developer-tools/developer-tools?currentflipperobject=73543fa58dda72c632a376b97104ff78). Qt designer produces XML files (.ui) which you can either convert to Python modules using a utility called `pyuic`, or load dynamically from your Python program.

You *do* have to write your Python code in a different editor, i.e. Designer is only the GUI designer part and not a complete IDE. They have an IDE in beta called Qt Creator, but I don't think it supports Python very well at this stage.

If you'd rather go with [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/), [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/) will output Python code.

Comment: PyQt is now from Riverbank Software.  (QT is from Nokia)

Comment: PyQt designer is pretty good. Integrating custom widgets into the designer can be a bit of the pain for new users because the help out there isn't great (all the guides I found just didn't work; I will probably make a correct how to guide when I find time and link it here), but once you get the hang of it the designer is pretty easy to use. The only slack I have with PyQt is that every time a new widget is instantiated at runtime, the compiled C++ code has to be loaded which ofc comes with overhead; this can cause long loading times with GUIs that creates hundreds/thousands of widgets.

Answer (score 2):

Use Glade + PyGTk to do GUI programming in Python. Glade is a tool which allows you to create graphical interfaces by dragging and dropping widgets. In turn Glade generates the interface definition in XML which you can hook up with your code using libglade. Check the website of [Glade](http://glade.gnome.org/) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If your using wxPython check out [BoaConstructor](http://boa-constructor.sourceforge.net/), it is a complete Python IDE with a GUI designer.

Comment: Wow, still at version 0.2 after all these years. -)

Comment: Good God, those screenshots look like they are from the 90's.

Comment: @WarrenP: There seems to be version 0.6.1 in SourceForge project page: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boa-constructor/files/Boa-Constructor/